# The meaning of SW_SHOW and SW_SHOWNORMAL

Tags: winapi

In my apps I use sometimes: `ShowWindow(MyForm.Handle, SW_SHOW)`.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548.aspx) for ShowWindow function has a section for `SW_SHOWNORMAL` that says

> "An application should specify this flag when displaying the window
>   for the first time".

Does it means that for every form (that I pass to `ShowWindow`) I need to keep a boolean var to see if the form was displayed or not and based on that I should use `SW_SHOW` or `SW_SHOWNORMAL`?

What is the deep meaning of `SW_SHOWNORMAL`?

Comment: MSDN gives you the difference right there behind your link: "If the window is minimized or maximized, `SW_SHOWNORMAL` restores it to its original size and position." This is what make it useful showing the window for the first time - you ensure it's not minimized or maximized.

Comment: @RomanR. - So in or case (Delphi) it doesn't matter much as the window (form) starts always as 'normal' size (non-minimized, non-maximized) as set at design time.

Comment: @RomanR. Well, it's more than that. You call `ShowWindow` passing `SW_SHOWNORMAL` whenever you want to switch from minimized or maximized to restored.

Comment: @Altar: this is Win API function. Delphi uses it or its variant when you make form visible as well as calling other API functions. so you basically don't even need to call Win API directly when showing form is in question. "First time" is only a use case example, you don't need any variables to distinguish this, at least for the purpose of showing a window.

Comment: I wonder why you call `ShowWindow` rather than `MyForm.Show`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - It is a special MDI child form that I hide (ShowWindow(Self.Handle, SW_HIDE)) when I don't need it. Also it has no TitleBar.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The term *normal* is synonymous with *restored*. This terminology dates back to older versions of windows and nowadays all the MSDN documentation uses restored rather than normal or normalized.

So, `SW_SHOWNORMAL` sets the window state to restored and makes the window visible. On the other hand, `SW_SHOW` simply makes the window visible.

Back in the day, restored was called normalized, minimized was called iconic, and maximized was called full screen. If memory serves, that older terminology was still in use in Windows 3.1, but was changed with Windows 95 and NT.

Comment: Back when windows were minimized to icons :)

Answer (score 7):

`SW_SHOW` is often used in conjunction with `SW_HIDE` so if you were showing/hiding a window for some reason (e.g. based on a user action) you would use them in tandem.  `SW_SHOWNORMAL` was originally used in the 'old' days when first showing a window.

`SW_SHOWNORMAL` is sometimes valuable if you want to make sure a window is not minimized (or maximized) at some particular point in the program (e.g. if the window might be minimized but you want to 'restore' it so the user can interact with it).

Comment: @Altar You should accept what you deem to be the best answer rather than the first, in my view.